# How can block wget to stop downloading for a certain directory (ie /photos)

Tags: command-line, wget

How can I stop commends like "wget -r", "wget" to prevent downloading images from the web site.  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^wget" bad_bot
<Limit GET POST>
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
   Deny from env=bad_bot
</Limit>
```

used this code in .htaccess file

Comment: It's possible to get around that by using any other using agent string with wget's `--user-agent=` option.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming you want to prevent others to download images from your website) There are some steps to avoid this, all of them can be bypassed. Examples:

- Use a [robots.txt](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/wget/wget_41.html)
- Tell your server to deny the wget User Agent
- Use some serverside scripting to limit downloads
- ...